# UIImageView: Change size to image size?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I've an `UIImageView` with content mode *Aspect Fit* of size 220x155. I'm dynamically inserting different images in different resolutions, but all larger than the size of the UIImageView. As the content mode is set to *Aspect Fit*, the image is scaled with respect to the ratio to fit the UIImageView.

My problem is, that if for instance the image inside the UIImageView is scaled to 220x100, I would like the UIImageView to shrink from a height of 155 to 100 too to avoid space between my elements.

How can I do this?

Comment: i have a same problem the image is set at center but get space in upper and lower side. how can i resolve it? please help me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I got you right, it would be something like this: get image size by:

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
CGSize imgSize = img.size;
```

calculate scale ratio on width

```
float ratio=yourImageView.frame.size.width/imgSize.width;
```

check scaled height (using same ratio to keep aspect)

```
float scaledHeight=imgSize.height*ratio;
if(scaledHeight < yourImageView.frame.size.height)
{
   //update height of your imageView frame with scaledHeight
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Based on Michael's answer, here's a complete method

```
+ (CGSize)makeSize:(CGSize)originalSize fitInSize:(CGSize)boxSize
{
    float widthScale = 0;
    float heightScale = 0;

    widthScale = boxSize.width/originalSize.width;
    heightScale = boxSize.height/originalSize.height;

    float scale = MIN(widthScale, heightScale);

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(originalSize.width * scale, originalSize.height * scale);

    return newSize;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit for Steven Stefanik's answer: This method breaks when originalSize is {0, 0}. Maybe consider these changes

```
-(CGSize)makeSize:(CGSize)originalSize fitInSize:(CGSize)boxSize
{
    if (originalSize.height == 0) {
        originalSize.height = boxSize.height;
    }
    if (originalSize.width == 0) {
        originalSize.width = boxSize.width;
    }

    float widthScale = 0;
    float heightScale = 0;

    widthScale = boxSize.width/originalSize.width;
    heightScale = boxSize.height/originalSize.height;

    float scale = MIN(widthScale, heightScale);

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(originalSize.width * scale, originalSize.height * scale);

    return newSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last edit:

It seems I misunderstood the question.

To get the actual size you could try:

```
CGSize imageSize = img.size;
CGSize viewSize = imageView.frame.size;
CGSize actualSize;

if (imageSize.width > imageSize.height) {
    actualSize.width = imageSize.width > viewSize.width ? viewSize.width : imageSize.width;

    actualSize.height = imageSize.height * actualSize.width / imageSize.width;
}
else {
    actualSize.height = imageSize.height > viewSize.height ? viewSize.height : imageSize.height;

    actualSize.width = imageSize.width * actualSize.height / imageSize.height;
}
```

Comment: Well, that does not work. Let say my image is 440x200. When this image is inserted into my ImageView, it's size would be changed to 220x100 to fit the UIImageView. Your code would set the height of the UIImageView to 200, whereas I would like to know the height of the image after the UIImageView has scaled the image.

Comment: You could always check for the height and only apply this if the image height is less than your current max height for the images and only then apply this kind of change.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure you understand my problem. Your code would change the size of the UIImageView to the size of my image -- that is not what I want. I would like my image to fit inside my 220x115 box. But when the ratio of the image is not like the ratio of my 220x115 box, sometimes is is wider than higher which gives white space in the top and bottom of the UIImageView. To avoid this, I would like to shrink the height of the UIImageView to the height that it had downscaled the image to.

Comment: Sorry, at last I did. It seems that neither the imageView or the image inside it reflect the current scale factor used. You would have to find it out by yourself by checking the image size against the view size.