# ios 7:How to show images from photo album without strectch while placing it in uiimageview in larger size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My task is to get the images from photo album and show it in one `ViewController` which has one `UIImageView` in full screen. The problem am facing here is while showing the small size photos captured in camera are getting stretched when it comes to `UIImageView`

I have tried with all aspect mode for keeping the image as normal. but no luck

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701751/uiimageview-change-size-to-image-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image selected from Photo Album with same size then

```
self.photoImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;// is best

self.photoImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; //if you want to fill the large imageview size with selected photo

self.photoImgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; // if you want to fill the large imageview size with selected photo
```

Else you can try with below solution for resizing image before assigning to imageview.

```
 UIImage *uiImage=[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOrignalImage"];//UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage

    CGSize size;
    NSData *imageData;

    imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 1.0);


    UIImage *galleryImage=[self squareImageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];

    photoImgView.image=galleryImage;

-(UIImage *)squareImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    double ratio;
    double delta;
    CGPoint offset;

    //make a new square size, that is the resized imaged width
    CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.width);

    //figure out if the picture is landscape or portrait, then
    //calculate scale factor and offset
    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width;
        delta = (ratio*image.size.width - ratio*image.size.height);
        offset = CGPointMake(delta/2, 0);
    } else {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.height;
        delta = (ratio*image.size.height - ratio*image.size.width);
        offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2);
    }

    //make the final clipping rect based on the calculated values
    CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(-offset.x, -offset.y,
                                 (ratio * image.size.width) + delta,
                                 (ratio * image.size.height) + delta);


    //start a new context, with scale factor 0.0 so retina displays get
    //high quality image
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, YES, 0.0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz);
    }
    UIRectClip(clipRect);
    [image drawInRect:clipRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Accept my answer if it is useful or acceptable..!@Prabhu

Answer (score 1):

Set the content mode of your image view. Try this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I have tried but it seems like not working bro!!!. I think i have to share more info here to get you a clear picture. Let me show my coding

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say

"I have tried with all aspect mode for keeping the image as normal. but no luck"

You mean you used the contentMode or UIImageView?
e.g.

```
self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

or one of the others AspectFill is another common one fit letterboxes I think and fill scales past the edge until the entire screen is filled.

But if your image is too small then it is going to look stretched even if the aspect ratio is correct, as there just wont be enough data for a full image

Comment: All I need is image should not stretched when it comes to uiimageView.Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
UIImageView *someImage = [UIImageView new];
someImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
someImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```