# UIImageView length is redundant when using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I am attempting to present my UITableViewCell with an ImageView which has optional length. And here is my layout:

[image: my autolayout]

But my result look like this (redundancy from top and bottom):
[image]
[image]
How to resolve this?

Comment: first, lmao @ sample image.  Second, make sure you have vertical space constraints with constants == 0, to both the "Title Title" textview up top, and the buttons on the bottom

Comment: @AO certainly. I set that.

Comment: Did you try going into the view debugger to confirm that the extra space is indeed the UIImageView's extra height?  If you force the height to be a specific constant, do you still see that spacing?

Comment: I used UITableViewAutomaticDimension for row height in UITableViewDelegate. It's not a constant

Comment: Correct, I was trying to recommend ideas to debug

Comment: Orange area (above pictures) is from UIImageView. I set this background.

Answer (score 0):

problem is here with the `ContentHuggingPriority` and `ContentCompressionResistancePriority`.

try to use this

```
[NSLayoutConstraint autoSetPriority:ALLayoutPriorityRequired forConstraints:^{
    [yourImageView autoSetContentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis:ALAxisHorizontal];
    [yourImageView autoSetContentHuggingPriorityForAxis:ALAxisHorizontal];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that can detect the size of the image in your code.

1. Set a height constraint on the image view. The constant doesn't matter because you're going to change it later programmatically.
2. Make that height constraint an IBOutlet and connect it to the IB

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewHeight
   ```
3. Get the size of the image. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701751/uiimageview-change-size-to-image-size)

   ```
   UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
   CGSize imgSize = img.size;
   ```
4. Change the NSLayoutConstraint constant.

   ```
   self.imageViewHeight.constant = imgSize.height
   ```