# Change Image view frame depending on picked image (from image picker) frame SWIFT

Tags: swift, image, imageview, frames

I have an image view where there is a set frame but when the user clicks it and changes the image (UIImagePickerController) then I somehow need the frame of the image view to change to the frame of the image.

When they click the choose button for their image, this is the code that I run.

```
itemImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.itemImage.image = pickedImage as? UIImage
```

So the image comes out in the image view but i need some help finding a way to get the image view frame to change to the picked images frame.

This is what I mean by the frame not changing.

[image: Frame Not Changing]

Thanks

Comment: why not  `itemImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill `

Comment: or resize your view - This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701751/uiimageview-change-size-to-image-size

Comment: @MohmmadS Doesn't that stretch the image a bit?

Comment: @rbaldwin how would I implement the link you mentioned?

Comment: yes, but usually we change the image size not the imgView we fit the picture in it , not the view for the picture, imagine having a 4k image.. idk how are you planning to resize your imgView in it

Comment: @PeterDutton , .rbaldwin suggestion is changing the image aspect the imageView, as i suggested not vice versa

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's pointless to resize the imageView control.

Answer (score 0):

first you should get AspectFitSize with these method :

```
public func getAspectFitFrame(from: CGSize, to: CGSize) -> (CGRect, CGFloat) {
    let (hfactor, vfactor, factor) = getFactor(from: from, to: to)

    let newWidth = to.width / factor
    let newHeight = to.height / factor

    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    var y: CGFloat = 0.0

    if hfactor > vfactor {
        y = (from.height - newHeight) / 2
    } else {
        x = (from.width - newWidth) / 2
    }
    return (CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newWidth, height: newHeight), factor)
}

public func getFactor(from: CGSize, to: CGSize) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) {
    let hfactor = to.width / from.width
    let vfactor = to.height / from.height
    return (hfactor, vfactor, max(hfactor, vfactor))
}
```

after that you should modify your imageViewSize with newSize :

```
let (imageFitSize , _) = getAspectFitFrame(from : self.itemImage.frame.size , to : self.itemImage.image.size)
self.image.frame.size = imageFitSize.size
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your imageView already has some constraints applied to it. I'd suggest applying size constraints to it.

```
// declare these at the top of the file so that the constraints can be removed when new images are selected
private var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
private var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

// remove old constraint
widthConstraint?.isActive = false
// fix the imageview width to that of the picked image
widthConstraint = itemImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pickedImage.size.width)
widthConstraint?.isActive = true

heightConstraint?.isActive = false
heightConstraint = itemImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pickedImage.size.height)
heightConstraint?.isActive = true
```